# Python 3.4 tkinter checkbutton variable handling not working / responding

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

*EDIT* This has now moved to [Python 3.4.3 tkinter - Program freezes on declaration of IntVar or any other tkinter data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33713742/python-3-4-3-tkinter-program-freezes-on-declaration-of-intvar-or-any-other-tki) as that is the root of the problem which has now been solved. Basically, NEVER name ANYTHING "master" in Python 3.x using tkinter, it causes an infinite loop :( . My full code has now been removed as it is my coursework and wouldn't want people nicking it :D *EDIT*

I'm relatively new to tkinter and can't see where I'm going wrong. I have tried using a StringVar() and a regular string to get multiple entry fields to disable when a Checkbutton is on. Here's the frame that the problem is in:

```
class CActivity(tk.Frame):

def Clear(self):
    pass # To be completed

def Today(self):
    if self.todayVar == "ON":
        self.day.configure(state="disabled")
        self.month.configure(state="disabled")
        self.year.configure(state="disabled")
    else:
        self.day.configure(state="normal")
        self.month.configure(state="normal")
        self.year.configure(state="normal")

def createWidgets(self):

    self.title = tk.Label(self)
    self.title["text"] = "Add an Activity"
    self.title["font"] = ("Times New Roman",30)
    self.title["fg"] = "purple"
    self.title.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="W",padx=5,pady=5)

    self.todayVar = ""

    tk.Label(self,text="Activity Name:",font=("Times New Roman",15)).grid(row=1,column=0,sticky="W",padx=5,pady=5)
    name = tk.Entry(self).grid(row=1,column=1,columnspan=3,sticky="E",padx=5,pady=5)
    tk.Label(self,text="Priority:",font=("Times New Roman",15)).grid(row=2,column=0,sticky="W",padx=5,pady=5)
    priority = tk.Checkbutton(self).grid(row=2,column=1,sticky="W",padx=0,pady=5)
    tk.Label(self,text="Today?",font=("Times New Roman",15)).grid(row=3,column=0,sticky="W",padx=5,pady=5)
    today = tk.Checkbutton(self,onvalue="ON",offvalue="OFF",variable=self.todayVar,command=self.Today).grid(row=3,column=1,sticky="W",padx=0,pady=5) #problem possibly on this line
    tk.Label(self,text="Date (DD/MM/YYYY):",font=("Times New Roman",15)).grid(row=4,column=0,sticky="W",padx=5,pady=5)

    day = tk.Entry(self,width=2).grid(row=4,column=1,sticky="W",padx=2,pady=5)
    month = tk.Entry(self,width=2).grid(row=4,column=2,sticky="W",padx=2,pady=5)
    year = tk.Entry(self,width=4).grid(row=4,column=3,sticky="W",padx=2,pady=5)

    self.clear = tk.Button(self, command=self.Clear)
    self.clear["text"] = "Clear"
    self.clear["font"] = ("Times New Roman",15)
    self.clear["fg"] = "red"
    self.clear.grid(row=7,column=4,sticky="WE",padx=5,pady=5)

    self.back = tk.Button(self)
    self.back["text"] = "Back"
    self.back["font"] = ("Times New Roman",15)
    self.back["fg"] = "red"
    self.back["command"] = self.parent.Menu
    self.back.grid(row=8,column=4,sticky="WE",padx=5,pady=5)

def __init__(self, parent):

    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.pack()
    self.parent = parent
    self.createWidgets()
```

And here it is with a StringVar() instead of a standard Python string:

```
class CActivity(tk.Frame):

def Clear(self):
    pass # To be completed

def Today(self):
    if self.todayVar.get() == "ON":
        self.day.configure(state="disabled")
        self.month.configure(state="disabled")
        self.year.configure(state="disabled")
    else:
        self.day.configure(state="normal")
        self.month.configure(state="normal")
        self.year.configure(state="normal")

def createWidgets(self):

    self.title = tk.Label(self)
    self.title["text"] = "Add an Activity"
    self.title["font"] = ("Times New Roman",30)
    self.title["fg"] = "purple"
    self.title.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="W",padx=5,pady=5)

    self.todayVar = tk.StringVar()

    tk.Label(self,text="Activity Name:",font=("Times New Roman",15)).grid(row=1,column=0,sticky="W",padx=5,pady=5)
    name = tk.Entry(self).grid(row=1,column=1,columnspan=3,sticky="E",padx=5,pady=5)
    tk.Label(self,text="Priority:",font=("Times New Roman",15)).grid(row=2,column=0,sticky="W",padx=5,pady=5)
    priority = tk.Checkbutton(self).grid(row=2,column=1,sticky="W",padx=0,pady=5)
    tk.Label(self,text="Today?",font=("Times New Roman",15)).grid(row=3,column=0,sticky="W",padx=5,pady=5)
    today = tk.Checkbutton(self,onvalue="ON",offvalue="OFF",variable=self.todayVar,command=self.Today).grid(row=3,column=1,sticky="W",padx=0,pady=5)
    tk.Label(self,text="Date (DD/MM/YYYY):",font=("Times New Roman",15)).grid(row=4,column=0,sticky="W",padx=5,pady=5)

    day = tk.Entry(self,width=2).grid(row=4,column=1,sticky="W",padx=2,pady=5)
    month = tk.Entry(self,width=2).grid(row=4,column=2,sticky="W",padx=2,pady=5)
    year = tk.Entry(self,width=4).grid(row=4,column=3,sticky="W",padx=2,pady=5)

    self.clear = tk.Button(self, command=self.Clear)
    self.clear["text"] = "Clear"
    self.clear["font"] = ("Times New Roman",15)
    self.clear["fg"] = "red"
    self.clear.grid(row=7,column=4,sticky="WE",padx=5,pady=5)

    self.back = tk.Button(self)
    self.back["text"] = "Back"
    self.back["font"] = ("Times New Roman",15)
    self.back["fg"] = "red"
    self.back["command"] = self.parent.Menu
    self.back.grid(row=8,column=4,sticky="WE",padx=5,pady=5)

def __init__(self, parent):

    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.pack()
    self.parent = parent
    self.createWidgets()
```

In the case of the use of a standard string the program runs fine until you click on the Checkbutton at which point the Checkbutton goes grey then the program stops responding. In the case of the use of the StringVar() the tk window doesn't load at all, due to this frame being initialised during the initialisation of the window. Thanks for your help and if you would like the full code to help find the problem just let me know.

Comment: self.todayVar = tk.StringVar() is the line on which the error is in the example using this as the program just freezes when it reaches that line (used debug prints). I think it may have something to do with when StringVar() is referenced during the initialisation of the tk window?

Comment: @PM2Ring That's great, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a cut-down version of your code that functions correctly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

''' Toggle disable / normal of Tkinter widgets

    Written by PM 2Ring & R. Murray 2015.11.15
    See http://stackoverflow.com/q/33711472/4014959
'''

#Python 3 / Python 2 Tkinter import
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk


class CActivity(tk.Frame):
    def today_cb(self):
        if self.todayVar.get():
            state = "disabled"
        else:
            state = "normal"
        #print(state)

        self.day.configure(state=state)
        self.month.configure(state=state)
        self.year.configure(state=state)


    def create_widgets(self):
        title_text = ("Click the 'Today' Checkbutton to\n"
            "disable / enable date Entry widgets")
        title = tk.Label(self, text=title_text)
        title.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="W", padx=5, pady=5)

        self.todayVar = tk.IntVar()

        tk.Label(self,text="Today").grid(row=1, column=1, 
            sticky="W", padx=0, pady=5)
        today = tk.Checkbutton(self, variable=self.todayVar, 
            command=self.today_cb)
        today.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="W", padx=0, pady=5)

        #Date Entry widgets
        tk.Label(self,text="Day").grid(row=3, column=1,
            sticky="W", padx=2, pady=5)
        self.day = tk.Entry(self, width=2)
        self.day.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky="W", padx=2, pady=5)

        tk.Label(self,text="Month").grid(row=3, column=2,
            sticky="W", padx=2,pady=5)
        self.month = tk.Entry(self, width=2)
        self.month.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky="W", padx=2, pady=5)

        tk.Label(self,text="Year").grid(row=3, column=3,
            sticky="W", padx=2, pady=5)
        self.year = tk.Entry(self, width=4)
        self.year.grid(row=4, column=3, sticky="W", padx=2, pady=5)


    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.pack()
        self.parent = parent
        self.create_widgets()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    master = tk.Tk()
    master.title("Disable widgets demo")
    frame = CActivity(master)
    master.mainloop()
```

There are a couple of problems with your code.

Your `createWidgets` method saves the date `Entry` widgets into *local* variables, eg `day`, but they need to be in instance attributes, like `self.day`, so they can be accessed by the `Checkbutton`'s callback method.

Another problem is that you're calling the `.grid` method on the same line as the widget constructor. That method returns `None`, so doing

```
day = tk.Entry(self,width=2).grid(row=4,column=1)
```

sets `day` to None.

It's ok to use `.grid` (or `.pack`) on the same line as the constructor if you don't need to save a reference to the widget, but it just won't work when you *do* need that reference. :)

I've simplified the `Checkbutton`'s callback method slightly, to reduce code repetition. I got rid of the `onvalue="ON",offvalue="OFF"` in the `Checkbutton`'s constructor since the default 0 and 1 is adequate for this task, IMHO, (but feel free to change it back if you like :) ), and since we're using a numerical state I'm using an `IntVar` rather than a string or StringVar.

I've also change the name of the methods to conform to [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) conventions.

---

You still have some confusion with local variables vs instance variables in your code. `day` is not the same thing as `self.day`, so you need to fix that, eg,

```
day = tk.Entry(self,width=2)
self.day.grid(row=4,column=1,sticky="W",padx=2,pady=5)
```

needs to be

```
self.day = tk.Entry(self,width=2)
self.day.grid(row=4,column=1,sticky="W",padx=2,pady=5)
```

Also, bear in mind what Bryan Oakley has said about widget `variable` and `textvariable` attributes requiring a reference to an instance of a Tkinter `StringVar`, `IntVar`, etc.

Comment: That works exactly how I wanted, I'll go and implement that in my code now. Thanks!

Comment: I still have exactly the same problem, so I think my mistake is elsewhere, though I was already probably making a mistake and it's great that you have helped me with that. I will put my full code in the question and it would be great if you could see what is wrong.

Comment: @R.Murray: Ok, but _please_ try to condense your problem down to a [mcve]. Not only does that make it easier to diagnose and fix the problem, it makes your question more valuable to SO, as it will be more likely to help future readers.

Comment: @R.Murray: My _guess_ is that you probably have a bunch of other errors similar to the `day = tk.Entry(self,width=2).grid(row=4,column=1)` thing causing havoc throughout your code, and using `somevar` where you need `self.somevar`. So hopefully, once you clean those things up your code will be a lot closer to working correctly.

Comment: I'm sorry but I just don't have time to do that as I am an A level student with tonnes of work to do and not a lot of time (not to mention that I am still really a novice with Python, let alone tkinter), I will post the full code in a sec (sorry!)

Comment: Full code posted with fixes based on what you've helped with so far :)

Comment: The full code is now up with correct indentation and I think all of the local and instance variable problems are fixed (emphasis on "I think") but STILL I have the same issue of the tk window never loading up, and the freezing point is STILL the line: self.todayVar = tk.IntVar() ... I'm starting to lose my mind xD

Comment: @R.Murray: Weird. Your new code runs perfectly for me, on Python 2.6.6 on Linux (once I modify the import statement).

Comment: Weird indeed - I'm using Python 3.4.3 on Windows 7. I will create a new question regarding this with a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example which I just created as suggested as this getting quite cluttered! I'll comment again with a link to the new thread in a sec,

Comment: here's the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33713742/python-3-4-3-tkinter-program-freezes-on-declaration-of-intvar-or-any-other-tki

Answer (score 0):

The `variable` and `textvariable` attributes require a reference to an instance of a Tkinter `StringVar`, `IntVar`, `DoubleVar` or `BooleanVar`. You cannot use normal variables.

Second, you must use the `get` method of these variables in order to retrieve the values before comparing them in an `if` statement.

```
self.todayVar = StringVar()
...
today = tk.Checkbutton(..., variable=self.todayVar, ...)
...
if self.todayVar.get() == "ON":
```

Comment: That's great to have cleared up but if you read the above answer thread you will see that the problem has evolved somewhat now! Any advice you can give on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you reproduce the OP's problem with the new code, Bryan? As I said above, it works for me, and I can't see any potential trouble-spots.